# Price showing as 0 on product grid but correct price when you click into it

Tags: product, price

I have imported some products into Magento and I am faced with this problem.
[image]
[image]

I don't really know where to start debugging this. This is how I am setting the price at the moment (removed some data for clarity):

```
$productData = array(
        'price'                             => $sellPrice          
    );
$mc = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api();
$mc->update($productId, $productData);
```

Should I be updating another attribute somewhere?

**Edit** When debugging the SQL that runs, I can see in `Grid.php` `_prepareCollection` that `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');` is called but when I do `(string)$this->getCollection()->getSelect()` the price column isn't selected in the SQL which I assume is why they all default to zero.

Comment: Did you rebuild the price indexes after saving?

Comment: I didn't, running it now.

Comment: @Marius - I have just re-indexed everything and it's still showing as above.

Comment: When you have more than one storeview, what storeview is chosen above the product grid? And I would dig into the collection and check what is selected to show in the grid. Whatever is selected is wrong - but I'm to lazy... ahh have too much work to do, to dig into the code.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - The snide comments about debugging aside, the price isn't in the collection SQL that runs.

Comment: Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - See my edit to see where the SQL comes from. I must admit, I am little confused as to how the data is mapped to that grid.

Comment: how big is the sql? should be at least one sheet of paper. The problem is, that addAttributeToSelect afaik doesn't change the select object, but prepares everything and saves it into an array. Therefore better try to `$collection->load(true)` which prints the fired query

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api` works so I'm writing this alternative.

```
$productId = 10; //replace with your product id
$sellPrice = 9.90; //replace with own price
$productData = array(
    'price' => $sellPrice          
);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($productId), //list of product ids to be updated
    $productData, //array with attributes to be updated
    0 //store id - 0 means "default values"
);
```

This always worked for me.

**[EDIT]**
For websites use this to add products to websites:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds)
```

and this to remove products from websites:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->removeProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

Comment: I get `Call to a member function getAttributeId() on a non-object` in `Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Action.php` line 69. The attribute it's complaining about is `websites` which I populate in the same way as the price but passing through an array of website Ids `'websites' => $productWebsiteIds,`

Comment: @webnoob for websites is a little different. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you be able to cast your eye over my edit please? I'm hesitant to change parts of the code until I understand what is causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into the same problem importing a large amount of products. After importing prices were showing an incorrect value when browsing but the correct price when viewing the product on the product page.

The solution: If you have a store with multiple views, you need to assign the problem products to those views and re-index.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by assign the items to the view? I assign them to a store, isn't that enough?

Comment: In my case, they were assigned on import but for some reason I had to reassign (within the admin panel) and re-index. Also ensure that the Price attribute is using the global value and not store value (if you've changed the defaults). Try a few problem products instead of the whole store to confirm.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit please? Editing 7000 items in the database via the admin panel isn't an option for me :)

Comment: You can select all the affected products and update them with the "**Update attributes**" drop down on the *Manage Products* view in the admin panel.